# Wrapping sudo & ssh command inside bash

Tags: bash

I need to switch to sudo user and then run a command on remote server using SSH

Actual command

```
docker stats --no-stream --format  "\"{{ .Name }}\^C{\"memory\":{\"raw\":\"{{ .MemUsage }}\",\"percent\":\"{{ .MemPerc }}\"},\"Node\":\"{{ \"`hostname -i`\" }}\",\"cpu\":\"{{ .CPUPerc }}\"},"
```

running from ssh also works

```
ssh 1.2.3.4 'docker stats --no-stream --format  "\"{{ .Name }}\^C{\"memory\":{\"raw\":\"{{ .MemUsage }}\",\"percent\":\"{{ .MemPerc }}\"},\"Node\":\"{{ \"`hostname -i`\" }}\",\"cpu\":\"{{ .CPUPerc }}\"},"'
```

But when i try to pass it as sudo su - core -c its not working because " pattern matching. How to properly wrap this command ?

```
sudo su - core -c 'ssh 1.2.3.4 'docker stats --no-stream --format  "\"{{ .Name }}\^C{\"memory\":{\"raw\":\"{{ .MemUsage }}\",\"percent\":\"{{ .MemPerc }}\"},\"Node\":\"{{ \"`hostname -i`\" }}\",\"cpu\":\"{{ .CPUPerc }}\"},"''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working with here document

```
 sudo su - core << 'END_SUDO'
    ssh self << 'END_SSH'
    docker stats --no-stream --format  '"{{ .Name }}{"memory":{"raw":"{{ .MemUsage }}","percent":"{{ .MemPerc }}"},"Node":"{{ "'"$(hostname -i)"'" }}","cpu":"{{ .CPUPerc }}"},'
    END_SSH
    END_SUDO
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to first run `sudo su - core` to change user and then running the command. After that you could just write `exit` to return to the original user. But i guess you want a one-liner. In that case i think this should work, unfortunately i can't test it:

```
sudo su - core -c ssh\ 1.2.3.4\ 'docker stats --no-stream --format  "\"{{ .Name }}\^C{\"memory\":{\"raw\":\"{{ .MemUsage }}\",\"percent\":\"{{ .MemPerc }}\"},\"Node\":\"{{ \"`hostname -i`\" }}\",\"cpu\":\"{{ .CPUPerc }}\"},"'
```